# How do I include a range of lines of a file in php?

Tags: php, file, echo, lines

I am aware that this:

```
    <?php

$file2 = file('website/files/myfolder/file.html');

echo $file2[8];
echo $file2[9];
echo $file2[10];
echo $file2[11];


?>
```

would give me the contents on lines 8,9,10,11 in the file.html file, however I would like to do this for about 100 lines ranging from lines 23 to 116. How would I accomplish this without using the echo $file2[NUMBER]; one hundrend times?

Another way to explain what I am trying to do would be possibly if I could do this in php:

`echo $file2[23-116];`

obviously this will not work but that is the concept.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you don't need the range to by dynamic, place the required lines in a separate file and just `include` it.

Comment: I do need it to be dynamic because the file I plan on including will be constantly updated and included by multiple other files. For example, when I update it, I will put new content on a new line. Say two files are already including this one. One of the files will include lines 23-116 and the next file lines 117-200. When I update the file, you can see the content gets "bumped" to the next file including it. If you have any other suggestions or ways to accomplish this please let me know.. Thanks!

Comment: @codman212 I think you need to Google search for `PHP Pagination`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a loop like so

```
$data = file('website/files/myfolder/file.html');
for ($i = 23; $i <= 116; $i++) {
    echo $data[$i];
}
```

- http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Or you could splice the data:

```
$data = file('website/files/myfolder/file.html');
echo implode(PHP_EOL, array_splice($data, 23, 116 - 23));
```

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
$file = file('website/files/myfolder/file.html');

foreach( range( 23, 116) as $i) {
    echo $file[$i]; 
}
```