# How to save lines of code with stacktrace in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel-7

I'm currently trying to create an exception dashboard something similar to sentry/ Bugsnag for my Laravel projects. But I've been having trouble trying to save lines of code together with the stacktrace and am unable to find any documentation.

For example: [How sentry returns in dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9Vbg.png)

```
$apiAddress = config('errorTracker.GetFromEnv.apiAddress');
$apiKey = config('errorTracker.GetFromEnv.apiKey');
$evironment = config('errorTracker.GetFromEnv.environment');

$json = [
    'api_key' => $apiKey,
    'environment' => $evironment,
    'user' => (Auth::check()? Auth::id():'unknown'),
    'system' => Browser::platformFamily(),
    'message' => $exception->getMessage():'Exception',
    'location' => $exception->getFile(),
    'line' => $exception->getLine(),
    'trace' => $exception->getTrace()
];

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, $apiAddress );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST" );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("content-type: application/json"));
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($json) );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

$response = curl_exec($curl);
```

I want to create something similar to this, when an error accours in one of my projects, a package sends usefull data like the stacktrace to out API.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'd suggest reading [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get some pointers on writing a proper question. You need to show what you're trying to do (in an example), what you've tried and explain where exactly it's going wrong.

Comment: @El_Vanja thanks for suggesting changing the formulation of the question, I agree its a little vague. I hope this changed the idea a little.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you don't know how to get the line of code where the exception happened (and perhaps some surrounding lines for context)?

Comment: @El_Vanja Exactly

Comment: You have the file in `$exception->getFile()`. The rest is just straightforward [file reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10491162/how-do-i-include-a-range-of-lines-of-a-file-in-php). You can decide how many lines around `$exception->getLine()` you want to include.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, I have not thought of that yet. thank you very much ill let you know if I can figure it out!